# How can I use XCode's libc++ with top-of-trunk clang?

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, clang, libc++

When compiling this file

```
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::vector<int> IntVector;
}
```

using the version of clang shipping with Xcode, I can tell clang to use llvm's libc++ like this:

```
$ clang -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ t.cpp -lc++ -o t
```

When using a self-built version of clang, however, this command does not work because clang cannot find libc++:

```
$ /my/clang -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ t.cpp -lc++ -o t
t.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'vector' file not found
#include <vector>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I know that I can download, build and install libc++ from sources; however, I'd much rather use the version shipping with Xcode.

How can I use the libc++ version shipping with Xcode when using my own version of clang?

Comment: To start with, you might want to use `clang++` instead. Secondly, when you built clang, did you tell it where the library headers were located?

Comment: Furthermore, you have to specify the development sysroot: `clang++ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk` etc.

Comment: How would that help finding libc++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First determine where libc++ is:  It will be located within the Xcode app itself.  If you have trouble finding it, preprocess a HelloWorld using Xcode and inspect it for the path to a std header.

Then on your command line point to the `include` directory with `-I`.  You can also use `-nostdinc++` to guarantee that no other std headers will be looked for:

```
$ /my/clang -std=gnu++11 -stdlib=libc++ t.cpp -nostdinc++ -I<path-to-libcxx>/include
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job. It appears that the version shipping with Xcode 4 is incompatible with t-o-t clang, giving compiler errors in some of the headers. The version from the Xcode 5 previews seem to work, though.